# XML XPath: conditionally selecting table cell

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working on a project that has the below markup structure. The objective is to select `The brown fox` (Phrase column), if the table heading contains `Developer(s)` (as shown below). Is this possible?

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"><abbr title="Number">Number</abbr></th>
      <th scope="col">Phrase </th>
      <th scope="col">Developer(s)</th>
      <th scope="col">Pineapple</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >1.</td>
      <td>"<a href="#first">The brown fox</a>"</td>
      <td>Bob Smith</td>
      <td>Cool Joe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Xpath will get the expected text

```
'//table[tr/th[. = "Developer(s)"]]/tr[2]/td[2]/a/text()'
```

Comment: Nice solution, this works well, thank you! What does the dot (.) do in the th condition?

Comment: it means `this node` :).

Comment: This solution assumes that the target `td` is ***always in the second position*** rather than in the `Phase` column as requested.  See [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611190/290085) to select the column based on the heading instead of its position.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//table[tbody/tr/th="Developer(s)"]
       /tbody/tr/td[position() - 1 =
                    count(../../tr/th[normalize-space()="Phrase"]
                          /preceding-sibling::th)]
```

selects the `td` elements in the same position as the `"Phrase"` `th` for the table containing a `th` with a string value equal to `"Developer(s)"`, as requested.